# TFS2018 Build CI Batch Changes Trigger stops does not execute

Tags: tfsbuild

This feels like an odd one.  In my current setup, if I enable batch changes on the CI trigger, the trigger is never executed.  I'm not even sure where to start on this issue.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the settings?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. Once you select `Batch changes` option, when a build is running, the system waits until the build is completed and then queues another build of all changes that have not yet been built. You need to check the following items:

1. Whether there is a build running.
2. Whether you have specify correct path filters

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Yes, I've checked up to this point.  My issue comes when I enable Batch changes, it won't trigger any builds.  I'm concerned this might be an issue with my configuration or something corrupted.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side, could you try to create a new build definition to have another try?

Comment: I have.  I've built about 3.  Each pointing to different source branches.  (TFVC)

Comment: What I have not done is try it in a different project.

Comment: You could try in another team project to check the result.